# How to create VB box which have a drop down value and click button

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to automate Website login :

---

```
Sub Auto_open()

login

End Sub


Sub login()
Dim IntExpl As Object
Set IntExpl = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim dd As Object
Dim dd1 As Object
Dim dd2 As Object
Dim dd3 As Object

With IntExpl
      .navigate Worksheets("Workbook").Range("B2")
      .Visible = True
     ' If (.Document.getElementById("LoginUsername").exist) Then
       Do Until IntExpl.ReadyState = 4
       Loop
       Set dd = .Document.getElementById("LoginUsername")
       dd.Value = Worksheets("Workbook").Range("C2")
       dd.Click
       Set dd1 = .Document.getElementById("LoginPassword")
       dd1.Value = Worksheets("Workbook").Range("D2")
       dd1.Click
       Set dd2 = .Document.getElementById("loginBtn")
       dd2.Click

End With
End Sub
```

---

### And workbook as :

```
Website    Url              Login id               Password
HPS      Masasas .com            0000123        1234
Webex    asasas .com             0000123        1234
```

---

Now ..

I want to create a macro in vb ..when macro run its as following window :

1. A small window should be open which have a "Website" drop down menu which contain all the values present in website column.
2. When user select particular website : that url , username , password should be used in marco..

Comment: Have you looked into the concept of UserForms?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a User Form.  To do so, from the VBA window, choose Insert and User Form.  From there, add a combo box and a command button.  You can use this code to fill the combo box with your options:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 'We want the box to fill as soon as the form appears
Dim sites As Range

For Each sites In Range("B2:B3") 'Change this to suit your actual range
  Me.ComboBox1.AddItem sites.Value
  Next sites

End Sub
```

For the command button to execute the code, use this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim siteName As String
Dim URL As String
Dim user As String
Dim password As String
Dim site As Range
Dim IntExpl As Object
Set IntExpl = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim dd As Object

siteName = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
Set site = Range("B2:B3").Find(siteName, ,xlValues,xlWhole)
'These variables will let you log in using arbitrary credentials instead of ones called explicitly
URL = site.Offset(0,1)
user = site.Offset(0,2)
password = site.Offset(0,3)

With IntExpl
  .navigate URL
  .Visible = True
   Do Until IntExpl.ReadyState = 4
   Loop
   Set dd = .Document.getElementById("LoginUsername")
   dd.Value = user
   dd.Click
   Set dd = .Document.getElementById("LoginPassword")
   dd1.Value = password
   dd1.Click
   Set dd = .Document.getElementById("loginBtn")
   dd.Click

 End With
End Sub
```

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: I'm on my cell, so I can't test it now, but glancing at it, I think if you change Me.ComboBox1.Value to UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value (or whatever you named your user form), it should work. I'll give it a try in excel later today and post an edit once I confirm it's working.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get it to work after making that change.  I have edited the answer to show the working code.